# Dreamweaver CS4 - How do you preview in Browser?

Tags: dreamweaver, cs4

I'm new to Dreamweaver CS4 and making my first website. I've watched a lot of tutorials and they all just click the Preview in Browser button and they can see what their page looks like in Firefox/IE/etc.

But when I click Preview in Browser a new Firefox window opens up and it goes to my homepage and that's it.

What do I need to setup in order be able to preview in firefox?

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Dreamweaver, although I have it as part of CS4. But I just now opened up the app, created a test HTML page, saved it, and hit F12 (Preview in Browser). And there was my test page. I honestly don't know what you could be doing wrong. I thought it might be that you didn't save your file, but you get a warning dialog if you try to preview without doing that.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around I fixed the problem myself.

First I had to go to manage site and edit the basic preferences on my website.
I had to make sure the 'URL to browse to the root of your site" is valid.

In my case it I had to add:

file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Linda/My%20Documents/website1/